# Fiddler: View Internet and Transport layer details

Tags: fiddler

Is there any way I can view IP header and TCP header in fiddler. Do I need to write a script or is it even more simpler than this? I have just started using fiddler.

Comment: I believe Wireshark is for that task, Fiddler is for HTTP only.

Comment: Curious: What specific information are you looking for?

Comment: @EricLaw: I wish to see the TCP packets which are sent between client and server apart from the HTTP request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler is a HTTP proxy.  So no you won't get info about the TCP or the IP layers of the stack.

To get that you can use one of the following tools.

- Network Monitor - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en
- Wireshark - http://www.wireshark.org/